# exe, dl - защита

Tags: c#, gui, dll, клиент-сервер, pe

у меня клинт-серверное ПО
клиент GUI, хочу его и защитить. 
чтобы они не расковыряли-не поломали короче
2D игрушка

и по мимо него есть ещё dll, exe

будьте так добры если кто в теме рассказать
как можно моё чудо защитить))

Comment: `как можно моё чудо защитить` - никак. C# это довольно открытый язык, который довольно просто "вскрывается", можете конечно сделать обфускацию, "школоту" может и отгонит, но знающих людей вряд-ли. Самая лучшая защита - это не выдавать клиенту то, что ему не требуется, хранить и обрабатывать все на сервере. Клиент - это лишь набор не знаю, картинок там, методов отправки/получения данных и все.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, ну, а как от профи то защититься? ну, допустим разные там известные фирмы компании по производству игр или по. которые тоже ведь на C# пишут то... как они тогда защищают свой продукт то?

Comment: Дайте мне хоть одну игру, написанную на C# (Unity например), которую не взломали. Вы подобное либо вовсе не найдете, либо найдете какой то проект, который вообще не сдался кому либо и его попросту ломать не выгодно, либо найдете проекты, которые чисто клиенты, а вся логика игры крутится на серверах и для запуска даже одиночной компании требуется доступ к этим серверам. Так что увы и ах, вы не защитите проект на C#, даже установив туда всеми ненавистный Denuvo, максимум на недельку отсрочите взлом, не более.

Answer (score 0):

Есть несколько способов защиты интеллектуальной собственности на C#.

1. обфускация. Если у вас довольно сложный алгоритм, то хорошие программы для обфускации сделают код абсолютно не читаемым, он будет собираться, но разобраться в нем будет крайне сложно.
2. Хранить часть логики на сервере, раз у вас и так клиент - сервер, сделать часть функций (критичных к краже) на сервере и дергать их из клиента.
3. Сделать часть или всю логику на языке, стойком к декомпиляции, например C++. Но не CLI/C++, а на простом, не управляемом.